# Add Named Range to Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am creating excel sheet which having named range created using code.

```
 ExcelRange namedRange = sheet1.Cells[2, startColumn + i, regionEndRow, startColumn + i];
 package.Workbook.Names.Add("NamedRange", namedRange);
 namedRange.Dispose();
```

After save the excel file I am trying to open the file. At that time its give me an error as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error097360_01.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file 'D:\ExcelInputSheet\Sheet.xlsm'</summary>-<removedRecords summary="Following is a list of removed records:"><removedRecord>Removed Records: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)</removedRecord></removedRecords></recoveryLog>
```

Is there any clue for this issue

Comment: Why do you dispose your namedRange object before you save?  Why call that at all?

Comment: I removed that Dispose() method. But it doesn't do any thing

Comment: yea but why `Dispose()`? Dispose *removes the variable from memory*, it does not delete the named range. You have to **delete the named range** if you want to get rid of it not just clear references to the variable...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the reason. I am using this code in a loop and the named range adding dynamically. In some times there are some names with spaces '&' character for the range's name. That's the issue. When sheet is opening it will discard all the named ranges which are invalid